# References inside animateinline

Tags: beamer, hyperref, animate

I am trying to hide references in an animateinline environment to show them on click.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \begin{animateinline}[step]{}
  \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{show reference}
  \newframe
  \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\ref{sec:test}}
  \end{animateinline}    
 \end{frame}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{frame}
 Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Error:

> pdfTeX error (ext4): link annotations cannot be inside an XForm \end{frame}

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot not put hyperlinks inside `animate` frames. The problem is not the reference itself but the fact that `hyperref` tries to put an hyperlink at the `\ref` location.

The solution is to enclose the `animateinline` with `\begin{NoHyper}...\end{...}` to prevent `hyperref` from adding a link. More info here: [Strange interaction between hyperref, listings and animate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184922/strange-interaction-between-hyperref-listings-and-animate)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
\begin{NoHyper}
  \begin{animateinline}[step]{}
  \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{show reference}
  \newframe
  \parbox[t]{0.8\textwidth}{\ref{sec:test}}
  \end{animateinline}    
\end{NoHyper}
 \end{frame}

\section{Test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{frame}
 Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @SLx64, alfC: A new version `[2014/06/20]` was just uploaded to CTAN. It automatically inserts `NoHyper`.

Comment: @AlexG, so `nohyper` is active by default?

Comment: Yes, if it is defined, that is, if `hypererref` was loaded.