# Strange interaction between hyperref, listings and animate

Tags: hyperref, listings, animate

I am trying to have a `listing` inside an `animate` environment. However I can't manage to do it if the `hyperref` package is loaded.

This is a MWE, obviously in the real application I need `hyperref` for other parts of the document. **Is there a workaround? Some option in `hyperref` for example?**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref} % comment this line to make the example work
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop]{5}
\begin{lstlisting}
listing inside animate
\end{lstlisting}
\newframe
text in frame
\newframe
\end{animateinline}

\begin{lstlisting}
listing outside animate
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The error is

```
! LuaTeX error (ext4): destinations cannot be inside an XForm.
<argument> ... resources {\the \pdfpageresources }\@anim@box 
                                                  \xdef \@anim@lastxform {\t...
```

The error is really an interaction between the three packages. `listing` works outside the `animate` or without `hyperref`. `animate` works without `listings` or without `hyperref`.

Possibly related: [Hyperref adds vertical space to listings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124986/hyperref-adds-vertical-space-to-listings) which gives me the idea that `listings` uses some `hyperref` feature if the package is previously (?) loaded. Something like this is described in the Section 5.3 in the `listings` package manual.

Comment: just a side note, I've read that \usepackage{hyperref} should be put at the end, after all other packages are loaded.

Comment: @Nasser, yes but it still fails in the same way, I'll edit to remove the distraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that package `animate` has to use `XForm` objects for the appearance streams of the annotation. There pdfTeX does not allow destinations, which are automatically added by `hyperref` for the listings.

A workaround is environment `NoHyper` of package `hyperref`, which disables the `hyperref` stuff temporarily:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{NoHyper} 
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop]{5}
\begin{lstlisting}
listing inside animate
\end{lstlisting}
\newframe
text in frame
\newframe
\end{animateinline}
\end{NoHyper}

\begin{lstlisting}
listing outside animate
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Automated solution

The environment `NoHyper` can be put into environment `animateinline`. The following example uses package `etoolbox` for the patching:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd\animateinline{\NoHyper}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch \string\animateinline}%
}
\apptocmd\endanimateinline{\endNoHyper}{}{%
  \errmessage{Cannot patch \string\endanimateinline}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop]{1}
\begin{lstlisting}
listing inside animate
\end{lstlisting}
\newframe
text in frame
\newframe
\end{animateinline}

\begin{lstlisting}
listing outside animate
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works... Why is that? I don't see any links generated in normal `listings`. Is this something that `listings` does. Or is it `hyperref` that behaves like this for all environments (i.e. all `begin...end`s)? Is there an option to make `hyperref` skip `listings` or better yet skip anything inside `animateinline`?

Comment: @alfC: Destinations are link targets. For example, a line in a listings can be referenced and the link jumps to the referenced line.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that `listings` have potential link destinations at all lines. (How are they references `\ref{mylisting:line20}`?

Comment: @alfC: As usual: `\label` in the referenced line and `\ref` or friend for the reference. With some features like `mathescape` you can smuggle in the `\label`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I found this limitation of `animate` before, so this is very useful. Maybe (@AlexG) `animate` should disable temporarely `hyperref` by default; although that could cause surprises.

Comment: @alfC: Also the whole listings can be referenced, if it uses key `label`.

Comment: That is the confusing part, why XForm is generated even if no label has been produced. But ok, that's how things are.

Comment: @alfC: In LaTeX `\label` comes *after* the referenced counter (e.g. the famous `\label` after `\caption`, not before). The time, when the counter is assigned a new value (`\refstepcounter`) is usually at the beginning (of the listings, of the line in the listings, of the caption, ...); that means a good place for the destination. Thus the destination is set without knowing, whether a `\label` is following.

Comment: @alfC: XForms have nothing to do with labels/links. XForms are at the core of `animate`s working. XForms are self-contained graphical/textual objects which can be referenced in the page content or as appearance of PDF annotations. `animate` uses XForms to store the content of the animation frames. They just cannot store links and link destinations. (Very much like `\includegraphics` and `\includepdf` don't support links in the included material.)

Comment: @AlexG, however `\includegraphics` behaves differently in that it fails silently (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14620/how-to-preserve-hyperlinks-in-included-pdf). Which may or may not be a desired behavior of `animate` (currently it is not, `animate` fails with an error). For example `animate` could tell `hyperref` to not generate links inside the `animate` environment. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @alfC: Thanks for the suggestion. In the next version or so, `nohyper` will be added.

Comment: @AlexG, yes, that will make `animate` work out of the box with many environments that currently fail with an error. (It will be mysterious why some hyperlink destinations don't work though.)

Comment: @alfC: For example, PDF XForm objects can be reused many times. A destination would no longer be unique.

Comment: Version [20140620] of `animate` inserts `NoHyper`. Thanks for telling about `NoHyper`. (It is not documented in the `hyperref` manual.)